# group by using mongoid in rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am using mongoid with rails4, I need group by result for supplying charts (statistics screen) for that I am using below code.

```
    @comments_stats = {}

    comments_data = Comment.where(:created_at.lte => Date.today-10.days).group_by {|d| d.created_at.to_date }

    comments_data.map{ |a| @comments_stats[a[0].strftime("%d-%m-%y")] = a[1].size}
```

it will give like

```
{
"1-1-2014" => 2,
"3-1-2014" => 1,
"4-1-2014" => 2,
"6-1-2014" => 4

}
```

but I want like below

```
{
"1-1-2014" => 2,
"2-1-2014" => 0,
"3-1-2014" => 1,
"4-1-2014" => 2,
"5-1-2014" => 0,
"6-1-2014" => 4

}
```

any one suggest how to simplify above query also.

Thanks 
Prasad.

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like this:

```
@comments_stats = {}
last_date = Date.today - 10.days

comments_data = Comment.where(:created_at.lte => last_date).group_by {|d| d.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%y")}
first_date = Date.parse(comments_data.keys.min)

(first_date..last_date).map do |n_date|
  day = n_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
  @comments_stats[day] = comments_data[day] ? comments_data[day].size : 0
end
```

I haven't tested it so it can have some issue

Comment: It's also possible to use `select` instead of map to further narrow things down